# If $M\prec (L_{\omega_1},\in)$, then $M=L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.

Tags: set-theory

This is exercise 13.17 of Jech's *Set Theory*:

> If $M\prec (L_{\omega_1},\in)$, then $M=L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha.$
>   [Show that $M$ is transitive. Let $X\in M$. Let $f$ be the $<_L$-least mapping of $\omega$ onto $X$. Since $f$ is definable in $(L_{\omega_1},\in)$ from $X$, $f$ is in $M$. Hence $f(n)\in M$ for each $n$ and we get $X\subseteq M$.]

There are two things that I do not understand.

First, $f$ is definable in $(L_{\omega_1},\in)$ from $X$ and $\omega$, so to show that $f\in M$, shouldn't we show first that $\omega\in M$?.

Second, if $f\in M$, the only way I see to prove $f(n)\in M$ for each $n$ would be to show that $n\in M$ for all $n<\omega$, but I don't see why this is true, as I can't even tell that $\emptyset^M=\emptyset$.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If $L_{\omega_1} \vDash \exists x \in 0^M$ then $M \vDash \exists x \in 0^M$, which is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general fact here is: If $M \prec N$ and $a$ is definable in $N$ from parameters that happen to belong to $M$, then $a$ is in $M$ itself.  This follow from the definition of elementary substructure and the definition of definability.  Recall:

$M \prec N$ iff $M\subset N$ and for any formula $\phi$ and tuple $\bar{p}$ of elements of $M$, $M\vDash\phi(\bar{p}) \Leftrightarrow N\vDash\phi(\bar{p})$.

$a$ is **definable** in $N$ from parameters $\bar{p}$ iff there exists a formula $\phi$ with free variables $x, \bar{y}$ such that $N\vDash \exists !x \phi(x,\bar{p})$ and $N\vDash \phi(a,\bar{p})$.

0, every finite number, and $\omega$ are all definable in $L_{\omega_1}$ from no parameters.